# Tensorflow docker export weights

Tags: python, ios, docker, machine-learning, tensorflow

Hi I've followed the Retrain tutorial of Tensorflow in order to retrain the last layer of the inception v3 machine.

The tutorial is here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/ 
and here:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0

after I've completed the retrain process I want to export all the network's weights in order to replicate the network on iOS using BNNS API.

I've found a tutorial here:
https://github.com/bignerdranch/bnns-cocoa-example

but I'm having some trouble since I'm not comfortable with python.

Can someone help me?

Since now I've tried to run this script from docker

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 2]))
weight_list = W.eval().tolist()
thefile = open('/tmp/weights.data', 'w')
thefile.write(str(weight_list))
thefile.close()
```

but I've received multiple errors.

Comment: Could you provide some details on the errors?

Comment: I believe that the error is due to my lack of knowledge of python... My question now become how can I modify the retrain.py script in order to extract the weights and bias of the retrained network? Or better how I can write a script that extracts these parameters?